# Unable to get session variable value symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session

I am saving a value in session inside a controller;

```
public function setSessionValue($key,$val){

   $session = $this->get('session');

   $session->set($key,$val);

   echo "Token is: ".$session->get('token');
}
```

Getting response as;

**Token is: e129cb3b547b6017a9f69fe30a96efed**

In another request I am retrieving that token value from session using another method;

```
public function getSessionValue($key){

   $session = $this->get('session');

   echo "Token is: ".$session->get('token');
   return $session->get($key);
}
```

Now response is:

**Token is: NULL**

My security.yml file as below;

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
```

My full controller class is as :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class BaseController extends Controller{

  public $request;

  public function setSessionValue($key,$val){

    $session = $this->get('session');

    $session->set($key,$val);

    echo "Token is: ".$session->get('token');
  }

  public function getSessionValue($key){

    $session = $this->get('session');

    echo "Token is: ".$session->get('token');
    return $session->get($key);
  }
}
```

And then I am doing something like;

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use AppBundle\Entity\UserData;
use AppBundle\Bl\LoginOperation;
use AppBundle\Controller\BaseController;

class LoginController extends BaseController
{
   /**
    * @Route("/login", name="loginpage")
    */
public function loginAction($request)
{
      /* more code */

      //storing token
      $this->setSessionValue('token',$obj->token);
      $this->setSessionValue('uid',$user->getUserId());
      $response = json_encode($obj);

      return new Response($response);
}
}
```

What can be the reason for it? I tried in various way but could not retrieve the value in second request.

Any idea will be very helpful for me.

Comment: what is "this" a controller?

Comment: yes, this is a controller.

Comment: How your session is created ? Is it Symfony Session or native PHP session ?
And why aren't you using the tokenStorage ?

Comment: It is symfony session. I can use tokenStorage. But it is a test and unable to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Traditionally one uses $session = $request->getSession() to access the session from inside of a controller.  I'm guessing that what you are calling a controller really isn't.  Or you are doing something else that is a bit strange.

Comment: I have added my classes in detail, can you please check once? If anything more needed please mention.

Answer (score 0):

With your informations I see one possible case:

In symfony you are login under one firewall (see the app/config/security.yml file)

```
import:    
    pattern:  ^/import$
                http_basic:
                    realm: "Secured Auth"
                provider: myprovider
main:
    pattern: ^/
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    logout:       true
    anonymous:    true
```

In this example case, if you are logged in under the main firewall, you won't be automatically logged under the import firewall. So if you set a variable in the session under the main firewall path, this variable **won't** be available under the path **/import**

You are mentionning another request where the session values (uid and token) aren't available but I don't see it in your post.

Symfony create an anonymous session when you aren't logged in, so your values are in this session. But if you log in and try to access to the session that won't be the previous anonymous session but a new created and authentificated one (related to a known user I guess). 
I hope I'm clear ^^'

Comment: I have not changed anything in security.yml(default one). Though I added it. Please check.

Comment: Ok isn't a security problem, please give us the full urls of endpoints, and your controller's code 

And have you check if the session is really created on your server side (vm/docker or something else)

Are you logged in on one of the endpoints and not on the other one ?

Comment: I have added my classes in detail, can you please check once? If anything more needed please mention

Comment: I updated my answer please see.
Maybe if you explain me your goal I'll can help you